# Higher order function for ClickableSpan

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, kotlin-android-extensions

I'm trying to capture the click on a textview with links. 
To achieve this:

- I created a BindingAdapter which has two params (a: TextView, clickListener: () -> Unit).
- Inside the BindingAdapter:

  - ````
    val clickableSpan = object : ClickableSpan() {
      override fun onClick(widget: View) = onClickListener.invoke()
    } ```
    ````
- In a ViewModel I created a `fun processUrl() { Code Here }`
- In the layout.xml:

  - `<TextView app:infowithlinks="@{() -> model.processUrl()}"`

All that works well, I would like when I click the link on the TextView be able to send the Url to the function inside the ViewModel.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should expand the `onClickListener` to accept the String. Then invoke it with argument.

```
  @BindingAdapter("infowithlinks")
    fun TextView.setOnSpanClickListener(clickListener:Function1<String, Unit>){
        val clickableSpan = object : ClickableSpan() {
            override fun onClick(widget: View){
              with(text as SpannableString) {
                val clickableSpan = getSpans<ClickableSpan>()
                    .first() // probably search correct one
                val start = getSpanStart(clickableSpan)
                val end = getSpanEnd(clickableSpan)
                val url = text.subSequence(start, end).toString()
                clickListener(url)
               }
            }
        }  
        //....

    }
```

On the xml you'll have

`<TextView app:infowithlinks="@{model.processUrl}"`

And in the view model

```
fun processUrl(url : String){

}
```

Comment: @WidexA/S Thanks for help me. I have a question, what do you mean expand the onClickListener to accept the String?.

Comment: @WidexA/S Thanks a lot Nikola, you gave me great ideas.